# Load error! (Internal Server Error) - concrete 5 sitemap

Tags: concrete, concrete5-8.x

==== Errors in console and logs ====

```
The error message is as follows Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSite() on null in \/var\/www\/xxxxxxx.org\/concrete\/src\/Entity\/Site\/SiteTree.php:41\nStack trace:\n#0 After some research, I found that this is happening because the locale was returned as null to getSite function. Not sure why this is happening. Could please let me know the reason this could be happening so that I can check on those possibilities as well
```

Exception logged:

```
/var/www/xxxxxxx.org/application/config/doctrine/proxies/__CG__ConcreteCoreEntitySiteLocale.php:8 Declaration of DoctrineProxies__CG__\Concrete\Core\Entity\Site\Locale::setSiteTree($tree) should be compatible with Concrete\Core\Entity\Site\Locale::setSiteTree(?Concrete\Core\Entity\Site\SiteTree $tree = NULL) (2) This was an exception I received before getting "Uncaught Error...."
```

I found some references related to this error

> concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/… Where the user
> describes the number of possibilities. But would need to help
> unerstand the reason why should I be checking the server settings for
> my error and what should I be looking for

The site has a multilingual sitemap but none of them works. The site is currently at version "concrete5 - 8.5.0".

Whatever related issue I was able to find were with earlier version of concrete 5 and the changes that were committed to resolve the issue already exists in this version

Some of the URLs that I found
https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/cant-load-sitemap-error-msg-inetrnal-server-error
https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/sitemap-no-longer-works-shows-and039internal-server-errorand039/
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/commit/2cf69ac90a8c8d1c7a451c9a82badf358cc74a1a

None of them points our the reason of this issue. It would be really appreciated if somebody can help me out the direction to figure out the reason of the issue and solution for it.

Enviornment Information are as follow:

```
# concrete5 Version
Core Version - 8.5.0
Version Installed - 8.5.0
Database Version - 20190301133300



# concrete5 Cache Settings
Block Cache - Off
Overrides Cache - Off
Full Page Caching - Off
Full Page Cache Lifetime - Every 6 hours (default setting).

# Server Software
Apache

# PHP Version
7.1.33-16+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

# PHP Extensions
bz2, calendar, cgi-fcgi, Core, ctype, curl, date, dom, exif, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gd, hash, iconv, igbinary, json, libxml, mbstring, mcrypt, memcached, msgpack, mysqli, mysqlnd, openssl, pcre, PDO, pdo_mysql, Phar, posix, readline, Reflection, session, shmop, SimpleXML, soap, sockets, SPL, standard, sysvmsg, sysvsem, sysvshm, tokenizer, wddx, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, xsl, Zend OPcache, zlib

# PHP Settings
max_execution_time - 120
log_errors_max_len - 1024
max_file_uploads - 20
max_input_nesting_level - 64
max_input_time - 120
max_input_vars - 10000
memory_limit - 128M
post_max_size - 50M
sql.safe_mode - Off
upload_max_filesize - 30M
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait - not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max - 150
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit - 0
mysqli.max_links - Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent - Unlimited
pcre.backtrack_limit - 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit - 100000
session.cache_limiter - <i>no value</i>
session.gc_maxlifetime - 7200
soap.wsdl_cache_limit - 5
opcache.max_accelerated_files - 100000
opcache.max_file_size - 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific? What you mean when you say the sitemaps don't work? What do you see? Any error messages in the browser's console or concrete5's logs?

Comment: The error message is as follows

**Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSite() on null in \/var\/www\/xxxxxxx.org\/concrete\/src\/Entity\/Site\/SiteTree.php:41\nStack trace:\n#0**

After some research, I found that this is happening because the locale was returned as null to getSite function. Not sure why this is happening. Could please let me know the reason this could be happening so that I can check on those possibilities as well.

Comment: I found some references related to this error 

https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/sitemap-no-longer-works-shows-and039internal-server-errorand039/#156530

Where the user describes the number of possibilities. But would need to help unerstand the reason why should I be checking the server settings for my error and what should I be looking for.

Comment: Exception Occurred: /var/www/xxxxxxx.org/application/config/doctrine/proxies/__CG__ConcreteCoreEntitySiteLocale.php:8 Declaration of DoctrineProxies\__CG__\Concrete\Core\Entity\Site\Locale::setSiteTree($tree) should be compatible with Concrete\Core\Entity\Site\Locale::setSiteTree(?Concrete\Core\Entity\Site\SiteTree $tree = NULL) (2)

This was an exception I received before getting "Uncaught Error...."